# How do I keep the user from exiting the program if there are any unsaved changes on the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms with a few numericUpDown controls and I want the program to warn the user when they click the exit button on the form, if they have unsaved changes, and if there are no unsaved changes to go ahead and exit. I have my save button click event to reset the all the NUD controls to 0 after each save.

I've tried several ways one of them worked, where I had all the numericUpDown control values summarizing and showing inside a textbox, and then I put the textbox inside the if statement and to trigger the messagebox if the textbox texchanged then tell the user about the unsaved changes or to exit if the textbox is null.

However after the save button click even clears all the controls, the textbox default value is 0 because it's getting that value from the numericUpDown controls. So when I click the exit button, It tells me that I have unsaved changes with a 0 value. That's not what I want. So I tried something different. And it works fine, if I only include one NUD control inside the if statement, but I have several controls to include and it will not work when I add the rest of the NUD controls. Like it shows on my code. I'm still very new at c# so I'm stuck. This is the code I have now.

```
private void btnExit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (numericUpDown1RB1Rep.Value <= 0 || numericUpDown1RB2Rep.Value <= 0 || numericUpDown1RB3Rep.Value <= 0 || numericUpDown1RB4Rep.Value <= 0)


      {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit this application?", "Exit",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
          Application.Exit();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
          return;
        }
      }
      if (numericUpDown1RB1Rep.Value > 0 || numericUpDown1RB2Rep.Value > 0 || numericUpDown1RB3Rep.Value > 0 || numericUpDown1RB4Rep.Value > 0)
      {
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("You have unsaved changes. Please save before closing this application", "Information",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {
          return;
        }
```

I'd like a method or solution where I don't have to add all the numericUpDown controls to this if statement and probably make it look a bit elegant. Or maybe, not have to use an if statement at all. I've trying to find help and trying different things for days.

Comment: You should make an array of controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow exit without save only when all your numericUpDown are zero or less then you need to change the test condition and use && instead of ||

```
if (numericUpDown1RB1Rep.Value <= 0 && 
    numericUpDown1RB2Rep.Value <= 0 && 
    numericUpDown1RB3Rep.Value <= 0 && 
    numericUpDown1RB4Rep.Value <= 0)
{
     // Exit block
}
else
{
     // Save block
}
```

Notice that you don't need a separate if in this case because if the condition is false obviously you need to save.

Said that, as pointed out in comments, using an array of your controls will make life easier

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    // At the form class level
    NumericUpDown[] numCtrls = new NumericUpDown[]
    {
        numericUpDown1RB1Rep, numericUpDown1RB2Rep,
        numericUpDown1RB3Rep, numericUpDown1RB4Rep
    };

    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }

    ... other form's methods or events.....

}
```

and inside the click event

```
if(numCtrls.All(x => x.Value <= 0))
    // Exit block
else
    // Save block
```

Comment: This code worked in doing what I want. Although when I click on the exit button, It doesn't let the user know that the exit button it's disabled due to the unsaved changes. I'll figure out how to fix that. Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried adding the If(numCtrls.All(x => x.Value <= o)) to the button click event and it's throwing an exception "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source'"

Comment: That's weird though!. On which line did you get the exception?

Comment: I'm getting that exception inside the exit button click event that's where I put that line of code. private void btnExit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      if (numCtrls.All(x => x.Value <= 0))
        
      {
          DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(" exit this application?", "Exit",
          MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
          Application.Exit();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
          return;
        }

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem if the variable _numCtrls_ is itself null. Are you sure that you initialize that array at the form class global level?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it correctly. I added: NumericUpDown[] numCtrls; inside the public partial class of the form.And then I added my array: NumericUpDown[] numCtrls = new NumericUpDown[]
                {numericUpDown1RB1Rep, numericUpDown1RB2Rep, numericUpDown1RB3Rep, numericUpDown1RB4Rep,}; under the: InitializeComponent(); and then I added: if (numCtrls.All(x => x.Value <= 0)) inside the button click event.

Comment: Yes, you are doing it wrong. Inside the form constructor you should use the global variable not declaring a new local variable and initialize it. Read about _variable scope_. So (in the form constructor) you should remove the declaration _NumericUpDown[]_ and write instead _this.numCtrls = ...._ In that way is the global variable that is initialized. At that point in the button exit event you have the global variable correctly initialized

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is adding NumericUpDown manually you can enumerate over controls :

```
private IEnumerable<NumericUpDown> GetNumericUpDowns(Control parent)
{
    for (int i = parent.Controls.Count - 1; i <= 0; i--)
    {
        if (parent.Controls[i] is NumericUpDown)
            yield return (NumericUpDown)parent.Controls[i];
    }
}

private void btnExit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var upDowns = GetNumericUpDowns(this).ToList();

    if (upDowns.Any(a => a.Value <= 0))
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit this application?", "Exit",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    if (upDowns.Any(a => a.Value > 0))            
    {
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show(
            "You have unsaved changes. Please save before closing this application", "Information",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and if you don't want to check all NumericUpDown controls you can add a tag to controls that you want to check (for example 1) and check only controls that have this tag :

```
private IEnumerable<NumericUpDown> GetNumericUpDowns(Control parent)
{
    for (int i = parent.Controls.Count - 1; i <= 0; i--)
    {
        if (parent.Controls[i] is NumericUpDown)
        {
            var upDown = (NumericUpDown) parent.Controls[i];

            if ((int)upDown.Tag == 1)
                yield return upDown;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mojtaba Tajik I tried this code, but it's not doing anything at all, the messagebox will not show at all and when I click on the exit button the program does not terminate.